# Memcached error for apache httpd 2.4

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, redhat, memcached, mod-ssl

I created an EC2 instance with Apache HTTPD 2.4 with mod_ssl version 2.4.34.  I've created a Memcached cluster on AWS ElastiCache version 1.6.17 with encryption in transit.

The goal is to have HTTPD use MemCached with TLS for the SSLSessionCache.  However, whenever a request is received, the server logs the following:

**vhosts.conf**

```
...
SSLSessionCache memcache:test-memcache.2dr943.cfg.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:11322
...
```

**ssl_error_log**

```
Could not find specified socket in poll list.: AH00790: scache_mc: error setting key 'mod_ssl-session:162534f25cf4152836459039d4c99263a346345e9366230f9a00394f593abcab' with 1447 bytes of data
```

I can verify the Memcached cluster is accessible and functional by using `openssl s_client -connect test-memcache.2dr943.cfg.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:11322`.

It seems HTTPD is unable to connect to the Memcache service with encryption in-transit.  Any ideas how to address the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `stunnel` to serve as a proxy to encrypt traffic for tools that do not support it by default.

You can configure stunnel like so:

**/etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf**

```
foreground = no
[memcache]
client = yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:11322
connect = test-memcache.2dr943.cfg.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:11322
CAfile = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-certs-bundle.crt
sslVersion = TLS1.2
```

Then you can update your httpd memcache configuration as follows:

**vhosts.conf**

```
SSLSessionCache memcache:localhost:11322
```